# How does RFC2898DeriveBytes generate an AES key?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, rijndael, rfc2898

I saw some code like

```
string password = "11111111";
byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("22222222");
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
RijndaelAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(RijndaelAlg.KeySize / 8);
```

I can see the key is generated by Rfc2898DeriveBytes with passphrase and salt. Then AES retrieves the key by GetBytes.

But the question is, what does RFC2898DeriveBytes do and what key.GetBytes(cb) do? Could anyone elaborate this? I couldn't get it from the documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RFC2898 refers to a password-based cryptography specification published in September 2000. Effectively, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` takes a password and salt to generate keys. The method it uses is known as PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function #2) and is defined in section 5.2 of RFC2898. From section 5.2:

> PBKDF2 applies a pseudorandom function (see Appendix B.1 for an example) to derive keys. The length of the derived key is essentially unbounded. (However, the maximum effective search space for the derived key may be limited by the structure of the underlying pseudorandom function. See Appendix B.1 for further discussion.) PBKDF2 is recommended for new applications.

For further details, see [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt).

As for what `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes` does, it returns a different key on each invocation; it effectively just applies PBKDF2 repeatedly with the same password and salt but also an iteration count.

This is outlined in RFC doc where PBKDF2 is defined as

```
PBKDF2 (P, S, c, dkLen)
```

where `P` is the password, `S` is the salt, `c` is the iteration count and `dkLen` is the length of the desired key.

The [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments) are in general very interesting and historically quite important. [RFC 1149](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1149) is quite important, as is [RFC 2324](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324).

Comment: it returns a different key on each invocation

But I found out the keys returned are all the same

Comment: @Kelvin: Are you sure that you're using it on the same instance of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`? It's effectively impossible to see the same bytes returned on successive invocations of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes` on the same instance of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.

Comment: RijndaelManaged RijndaelAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
string password = "11111111";
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("22222222"));
RijndaelAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(RijndaelAlg.KeySize / 8);
byte[] a = key.GetBytes(32);
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
  logWindow.AppendText(a[i] + " ");
}

Comment: @Kelvin: You're only calling `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes` once. So now I see the confusion. I said you'll see different output on successive invocations on the same instance. But you're not executing `GetBytes` on the same instance of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. You're executing the above code multiple times and seeing the same output. This is by design. The algorithm is deterministic.

Comment: Sry, still a bit confused.
code:
Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes()
RijndaelAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(RijndaelAlg.KeySize / 8);
ur comments:
But you're not executing GetBytes on the same instance of Rfc2898DeriveBytes
BUT:
key.GetBytes, isn't it excuting GetBytes on the same instance?

Comment: You've only called `Rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes` once. Can you explain in detail what you're confused by?

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the implementation in Reflector:

```
public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(string password, byte[] salt) : this(password, salt, 0x3e8)
{
}

public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(string password, int saltSize, int iterations)
{
    if (saltSize < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("saltSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    }
    byte[] data = new byte[saltSize];
    Utils.StaticRandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(data);
    this.Salt = data;
    this.IterationCount = iterations;
    this.m_hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(password));
    this.Initialize();
}


public override byte[] GetBytes(int cb)
{
    if (cb <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("cb", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[cb];
    int dstOffset = 0;
    int count = this.m_endIndex - this.m_startIndex;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        if (cb < count)
        {
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(this.m_buffer, this.m_startIndex, dst, 0, cb);
            this.m_startIndex += cb;
            return dst;
        }
        Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(this.m_buffer, this.m_startIndex, dst, 0, count);
        this.m_startIndex = this.m_endIndex = 0;
        dstOffset += count;
    }
    while (dstOffset < cb)
    {
        byte[] src = this.Func();
        int num3 = cb - dstOffset;
        if (num3 > 20)
        {
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(src, 0, dst, dstOffset, 20);
            dstOffset += 20;
        }
        else
        {
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(src, 0, dst, dstOffset, num3);
            dstOffset += num3;
            Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(src, num3, this.m_buffer, this.m_startIndex, 20 - num3);
            this.m_endIndex += 20 - num3;
            return dst;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: If you still have it, it would be useful to see the private functions of this class, particularly the part that does the iterating.

Comment: Use something like http://ilspy.net/ and check the code yourself :) I use Reflector, but should be the same.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ You can find the reference source on microsoft's reference source site, in this case [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs) http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rfc2898derivebytes.cs .